Trouble getting SAGA to work in QGIS 3.4 for Mac
I have been trying to get the SAGA toolbox to work in QGIS 3.4 but it does not show up. I have downloaded the SAGA Next Gen plugin for QGIS, and I have also downloaded SAGA from SourceForge and set the path in the QGIS settings (Preferences -> Processing -> Providers -> SAGANG -> SAGA Folder), but SAGA still does not show up in the processing toolbox.



Are you sure you use QGIS 3.4? It is 6 years old now?

Yes it is @katagena

The SAGA Next Gen plugin for QGIS is only for QGIS 3.22 and above... so it won't work for QGIS 3.4.
